# Java HttpUrlConnection is not connecting to 000webhostapp

Tags: java, http, request

```
URL url = new URL("http://subdomain.000webhostapp.com"); 
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
connection.getInputStream():
```

but the program gives ioexception for http error code 400. my browser too, it cant connect 000webhostapp

Comment: Does the code you’re running have the actual sub domain of your app in the URL or the literal word “subdomain”? If you see the same result in your browser, then this isn’t really a programming problem and is off topic for Stack Overflow. This FAQ says the most common reason for a 400 response from this service is an incorrect URL https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/i-am-getting-error-400-on-my-website-400-error-page-11508

Comment: please try to check URI

Comment: no, url was true. its about the service.